# Eclipse cannot find classes in grails-app/jobs folder with quartz

Tags: eclipse, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a grails project that uses quartz, but Eclipse cannot seem to find the files in the grails-app/jobs folder. I can manually add the quartz folder as a source folder and this allows it to find the quartz jobs. It seems like the eclipse plugin should be able to find this automatically - is this an issue with the plugin or is there a way to configure grails to find the jobs folder?

Comment: It would help if you would tell what version of Eclipse you are using. AFAIK STS doesn't have any issues with the jobs folder.

Comment: Using eclipse Juno. Also tried STS 3.0.

Comment: To test this further, I created a new grails project in STS and installed the quartz plugin. The jobs folder was created but not recognized as a source folder.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my project in STS 2.9.0M1 and the `jobs` folder shows up under `grails-app`. You are correct, STS doesn't seem to recognize this as a groovy source folder because "Open Type" doesn't bring it up any of the job files, but "Open Resource..." finds them.

I think this is because the `jobs` folder is a custom artifact type registered by the Quartz plugin. I don't think that the Eclipse Grails plugin is smart enough to find the custom artifact directory.

Comment: Ken, you're seeing the same behavior I am. It's kind of annoying though since then all of the quartz classes are redlined in Eclipse and show up as errors unless you manually add it as a source folder.

Comment: This sounds like an enhancement request for STS/Grails Plugin. You can report an enhancement request in their JIRA here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS